# How to Get Detailed Exception in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, exception

I do get exception message but response exception message is `TypeError: 'int' object is not subscriptable`.
The type of exception message I want:

```
FileName.py or ClassName
[Line Number] Message  Exception Message
```

I want to print this in try except.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would use `traceback` module to help get the details of the exception, including filename, line number and the actual error message.

**Heres an example**:

```
import traceback

try:
    # Insert your code here

except Exception as e:
    tb = traceback.extract_tb(e.__traceback__) # get the traceback object
    last_trace = tb[-1] # get the last trace
    line_number = last_trace.lineno # line number
    filename = last_trace.filename # file name
    function_name = last_trace.name # function or method name
    exception_message = str(e) # exception message

    print(f'{filename} or {function_name}')
    print(f'[{line_number}] {exception_message}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `traceback.print_exc()`

```
import traceback
try:
    a()
except Exception as e:
    traceback.print_exc()
```